# Issues upgrading app.component.ts @angular/router and nativescript-angular/router

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular-routing

I am trying to update my NativeScript application. My problems are with the new routing coming up with the upgrade from Angular. My package.json dependency:

```
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2"
```

after upgrading it:

```
    "@angular/router": "4.1.0",
```

Now I know that there is some new routing and I can't really get into it.

I am struggling updating my app.component.ts.

I cannot figure out how to update the routing, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import the directives in app.component.ts.

instead do this:

```
import {RouterExtensions} from "nativescript-angular";
@Component({
selector: "my-app",
template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"})
export class AppComponent{
constructor(private app : ApplicationService, private router:RouterExtensions ){
this.router.navigate(["/SOME-ROUTE"]);
}
```

And don't forget to import "NativeScriptRouterModule, NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)" in your module.

Comment: Thank you! The export.app.routes should work like this, shouldn't it? Or did I miss something? 
Edit: could you have a look at my updated code?

Comment: @Rüdiger do you have a "root" route? if not, you should add 
 - this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/XXX"]).
you don't need to inject "router" itself. use "RouterExtensions" instead for simple navigation (unless you have a good reason to use the basic router)

Comment: I update my post for the routes-element. I am not sure if you could use RouterExtensions already in Angular/Router@3.0.0, since the application got developed under this. If you could already use it there, it might have a reason that they did not do it (whatever reason that would be)